# How to print all output in terminal to pdf when executing function in python?

Tags: python, pdf

For example, I have a function that performs addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

```
def calculator(x,y):
    print("Summation between", x, " & ",y, "is: ", x + y)
    print("Subtraction between", x, " & ", y, "is: ", x - y)
    print("Division between", x, " & ", y, "is: ", x / y)
    print("Multiplication between", x, " & ", y, "is: ", x * y)
```

after calling the calculator function I get the output from the terminal, and output is:

```
Summation between 5  &  6 is:  11
Subtraction between 5  &  6 is:  -1
Division between 5  &  6 is:  0.8333333333333334
Multiplication between 5  &  6 is:  30
```

I want to get all output value from terminal and convert to pdf file. Thank for help me!

Comment: I'm sorry for off top. If you pass to print() several agrs, you don't need to add spaces. `print("Summation between", x, "&", y, "is:", x + y)` or `print(f"Summation between {x} & y is: {x + y}")`

Comment: You're really asking two questions: first how to capture the output from the program, second how to convert that to a PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks similar to the question here, with many answers for reference.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf